# Number theory (Divisibility)

Tags: divisibility

Find all tuples of positive integers
$(a, b, c)$ such that lcm$(a, b, c)$ = $ab + bc + ca\over 4$

I am stuck on this problem for almost 2 hours.
I tried the following things (however didn't reach the answer):
1)writing $a=dx,b=dy,c=dz$ and tried to proceed, but ended up making lots of cases number of cases, proceeding from that point seemed near impossible.
2)tried to directly make cases
3)Tried to bound by using i)AM-GM inequality ii)WLOG $a\ge b\ge c$, then $$c\le \text{lcm}(a,b,c)\le abc$$ but ultimately ended up with nothing.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd start by trying to construct examples.  Ignoring factors of $2$ we see that each term divides the product of the other two.  So every odd prime that appears must divide at least two of the terms.  If it divides all the you can divide out by it...

Comment: The only possible tuple is $(1,2,2)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4765924/14578

Comment: As I have previously commented to your later [question](/q/4765924), using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Coperatorname%7Blcm%7D(a%2Cb%2Cc)%3D%5Cfrac%7Bab%2Bbc%2Bca%7D%7B4%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Apositive%20integers&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [Japan Junior MO Finals 2020-3](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2005700p14037444).